# Error -26625: HTTP Status-Code=406 (Not Acceptable) - Unsure how to resolve this

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

**Please note that for the purpose of organizational security, I have masked sensitive data, including domains and IPs and anything else that might seem risky.**

In Loadrunner VUGen, I am seeing the following error in Output:

Investigator.c(901): Error -26625: HTTP Status-Code=406 (Not Acceptable) for "https:///complaints/api/assignWorkItem"

**Here is the Recording raw data:**

```
POST /complaints/api/assignWorkItem HTTP/1.1
Host: <DOMAIN MASKED>
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 222
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3209.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, cache-control, origin, x-requested-with, x-file-name, content-type
Expires: -1
Referer: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>/complaints/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: rxVisitor=1539275596972629MIT97TQHCU4S9862V80PDF73E8L4H; JSESSIONID=0000DjjVJqHfOtlUmwLBbNYe-44:-1; BizflowUserID=; REMEMBERAUTOLOGIN=; rememberID=false; BFLOGINTYPE=BIZFLOWSECURITY; WIHSTYLE=Basic
{"sessionInfoXml":"<SESSIONINFO KEY=\"<KEY MASKED>\" USERID=\"0000000130\" SERVERID=\"0000001001\" IP=\"<IP MASKED>\" PORT=\"<PORT MASKED>\" DEPTID=\"9000000000\" USERTYPE=\"U\" />","processId":859,"participantId":"0000000130"}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 15:15:24 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US

true
```

**Here is the Replay raw data:**

```
POST /complaints/api/assignWorkItem HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>/complaints/
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, cache-control, origin, x-requested-with, x-file-name, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>
Origin: https://<DOMAIN MASKED>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3209.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: <DOMAIN MASKED>
Cookie: rxVisitor=1539275596972629MIT97TQHCU4S9862V80PDF73E8L4H; WIHSTYLE=Basic; BizflowUserID=; REMEMBERAUTOLOGIN=; rememberID=false; BFLOGINTYPE=BIZFLOWSECURITY; JSESSIONID=0000-6LJaE1jyksQhhpnFLvGntL:-1; USEROS=NT
Content-Length: 222

{"sessionInfoXml":"<SESSIONINFO KEY=\"<KEY MASKED>\" USERID=\"0000000140\" SERVERID=\"0000001001\" IP=\"<IP MASKED>\" PORT=\"<PORT MASKED>\" DEPTID=\"9000000000\" USERTYPE=\"U\" />","processId":859,"participantId":"0000000140"}HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 18:21:56 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US

false
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I am missing and am hoping someone here can take a look and help me resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

In some systems, I've seen that the order of the headers threw errors - though the RFC ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)) says that the order shouldn't matter.

Have you tried to contact the server admin's to have a look at any logs?

Comment: I haven't tried that. If I contact them, is there anything specific I should ask about?

Comment: Sorry, this didn't send an email to me and I haven't been on the site since. Have you resolved this issue? You can try in postman to see if the order matters.

Comment: There may be server logs that will indicate what you are doing wrong. I'd try and work with the gateway admin guys to monitor any requests coming into the server as you send it in and they may shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Record

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Replay

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Give a try sending the correct Encoding header.